# Make SVG linear gradient fill a rect at a particular angle always

Tags: svg, gradient, linear-gradients

I need to fill rectangles of different aspect ratios and sizes with a single linear gradient that goes from top left to bottom right, and always at 45deg (not just from corner to corner).

Here's the code, which fills the rect from corner to corner, how do I make it be at 45deg?

Or a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/45nuu6L0/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100" height="50">
  <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
     <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#000"/>
     <stop  offset="0.48" style="stop-color:#000;stop-opacity:0"/>
     <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Isn't it the case where the gradient either goes from top left to bottom right or it goes at 45 degrees not both (except in case of a square)?

Comment: SVG gradients don't support that behaviour.  I don't believe there is any way to implement what you need without manipulating the SVG gradient dynamically with JS.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to have to play with the gradientTransform property of your linearGradient. As a starting point:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100" height="50">
  <linearGradient  gradientTransform="rotate(-45)" id="gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" >
 <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#000"/>
 <stop  offset="0.48" style="stop-color:#000;stop-opacity:0"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)"  />
</svg>

</body></html>
```